# How can a Thread or Runnable be killed instantly

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a little problem. I've a Service which get a SingleTon Thread when onStartCommand() is triggered.

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
{
   Thread t = myThreadFactory.getConnectionThreadWhatever();
   if (t.isAlive() && !t.isinterrupted()) 
   { 
     // do actions when thread is already alive
   } 
   else 
   { 
     // do actions to start and run the thread. e.g. t = new ConnectionThread().start();
   }
}
```

Now the Thread have a Runnable in a loop which is like (pseudocode!)

```
public static boolean isRunning = false;
public void run() 
{
   isRunning = true;
   while (isRunning) 
   {
       // open the httpconnection with a (read)timeout of 300 (long polling, whatever) 
   }
}
```

Now i=I would like to kill the Thread as soon as the connection drops in a Network Broadcast Receiver or whatever case.

What is the common way killing it instantly without waiting before the timeout (e.g. 300 seconds) occurred ?

Currently I am doing this in another class with

```
public void stopThreadconnectionInstantlyWhatever() 
{
   ConnectionThread.isRunning = false;
   Thread t = myFactory.getConnectionThread();
   t.interrupt();
}
```

Now the problem seems to be that the Thread may wait until the timout happen but every second is more battery usage which should be avoided. So.. any idea? :-)

Well, I could get the httpurlconnection with a singleton pattern aswell and kill it before the timeout appear, but this is just a case

Comment: @EmanuelSeibold Thread.sleep() throws an InterruptedException, and will halt upon being interrupted. Is there nowhere in the documentation for httpconnection for handling interrupts to the thread?

Comment: @EmanuelSeibold There's usually a graceful way of doing things. If there's something that waits or blocks for a long time, there's almost always some kind of way to wake it up without just terminating the thread. You deal with these things on a per-case basis. This was the point of them deprecating `Thread.stop()` because there's always better ways. We need more details about what is waiting, because that will change how to wake it up.

Comment: Check this video from Douglas Schmidt: http://youtu.be/wpEeZUjTiS4?t=4m17s

Answer (score 1):

Try to read [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp05236/)

> **Implementing cancelable tasks**
>  Nothing in the language specification gives interruption any specific semantics, but in larger
>   programs, it is difficult to maintain any semantics for interruption
>   other than cancellation. Depending on the activity, a user could
>   request cancellation through a GUI or through a network mechanism such
>   as JMX or Web Services. It could also be requested by program logic.
>   For example, a Web crawler might automatically shut itself down if it
>   detects that the disk is full, or a parallel algorithm might start
>   multiple threads to search different regions of the solution space and
>   cancel them once one of them finds a solution. 
> Just because a task is
>   cancelable does not mean it needs to respond to an interrupt request
>   immediately. For tasks that execute code in a loop, it is common to
>   check for interruption only once per loop iteration. Depending on how
>   long the loop takes to execute, it could take some time before the
>   task code notices the thread has been interrupted (either by polling
>   the interrupted status with Thread.isInterrupted() or by calling a
>   blocking method). If the task needs to be more responsive, it can poll
>   the interrupted status more frequently. Blocking methods usually poll
>   the interrupted status immediately on entry, throwing
>   InterruptedException if it is set to improve responsiveness. 
> The one
>   time it is acceptable to swallow an interrupt is when you know the
>   thread is about to exit. This scenario only occurs when the class
>   calling the interruptible method is part of a Thread, not a Runnable
>   or general-purpose library code, as illustrated in Listing 5. It
>   creates a thread that enumerates prime numbers until it is interrupted
>   and allows the thread to exit upon interruption. The prime-seeking
>   loop checks for interruption in two places: once by polling the
>   isInterrupted() method in the header of the while loop and once when
>   it calls the blocking BlockingQueue.put() method.

```
public class PrimeProducer extends Thread {
private final BlockingQueue<BigInteger> queue;

PrimeProducer(BlockingQueue<BigInteger> queue) {
    this.queue = queue;
}

public void run() {
    try {
        BigInteger p = BigInteger.ONE;
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
            queue.put(p = p.nextProbablePrime());
    } catch (InterruptedException consumed) {
        /* Allow thread to exit */
    }
}

public void cancel() { interrupt(); }}
```

Comment: Right. I think the key here is that anything that blocks should be throwing InterruptedException. The OP needs to show the code that is blocking